# Rows not loaded due to data errors

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

the below ctl file code is separated by **tab** so I am trying  the below code but its displaying :

5 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
Its not getting loaded in the table via sql loader

```
OPTIONS ( ERRORS=405737, SILENT=(ERRORS))
LOAD DATA
INFILE '/home/maliprat/public/RDDH_Extracts/AMER_20171215_EQUITY_ISSUE.dat'
APPEND
INTO TABLE ENCORE_APP.TEMP_RDDH_RAW_DATA_ISSUE
**FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'9'**
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
ISSUE_UBSID  "TRIM(:ISSUE_UBSID)",
TEST2 FILLER,
ISSUE_ASSETCLASS  "TRIM(:ISSUE_ASSETCLASS)",
ISSUE_ASSETTYPE  "TRIM(:ISSUE_ASSETTYPE)",
ISSUE_SECURITYTYPE  "TRIM(:ISSUE_SECURITYTYPE)",
```

my input file is below:

```
issue.ubsId     issue.majorVersion      issue.assetClass        issue.assetType issue.securityType      issue.active    issue.lastUpdatedTime   event.majorVersion      event.lastUpdatedTime   issue.status    issue.isoCfi    issue.isin      issue.nominalCurrency   issue.nominalValueOfUnit        issue.issueName issue.regSInd   issue.rule144AInd       issue.securityFormType
  issue.bbSecurityType    issue.cusip     issue.common    issue.cins      issue.valoren   issue.wertpapier        issue.ubsTradable       issue.restrictedListCode        issue.restrictedOffTime issue.restrictedOnTime
0200200307      13      EQUITY  STOCK   Common Stock    1       20171203120808000       15      20171203120810000       ACTIVE  ES----  SE0005994001    XXX     -9999.0 RLS GLOBAL PAID SUB     -9999   -9999   UNKNOWN Common Stock            107404309
       W7753D159       24542360                                -9999   -9999                   -9999
                                -9999   -9999.0                                 -9999.0 -9999   -9999.0         -9999
        -9999   0       SS      KA              -9999   2               -9999.0                 -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   4       20150316054137973               0       -9999   -9999   0       -9999   0       0               -9999   9668256 2735465 -9999.0 -9999   -9999   -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999           -9999   -9999.0
```

Comment: what is the error in that , 'Do i have to make any changes in .ctl file'?

Comment: Could you post a table description? Did you check the LOG file? Does the input file *really* look like that mess? How is "issue.ubsId" related to "0200200307" (as they both have to be inserted into ISSUE_UBSID column)?

Comment: I checked he log file , its reading the column i.e reading  5 records

Comment: Table ENCORE_APP.TEMP_RDDH_RAW_DATA_ISSUE:
  0 Rows successfully loaded.
  5 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.


Space allocated for bind array:                 255420 bytes(33 rows)
Read   buffer bytes: 1048576

Total logical records skipped:          0
Total logical records read:             5
Total logical records rejected:         5
Total logical records discarded:        0

Comment: wheres the rest of the ctl file?

Answer (score 0):

Well the key to finding the issue lies in the log & the bad file.. While executing sqlldr command using syntax as below :

```
sqlldr user/pass control=ctlfilepath/ctlfilename log=logfilepath/logfilename bad=badfilepath/badfilename
```

In this case the log file will contain the description of the errors & the bad file will contain the rejected rows.

For more information try entering `sqlldr` in the terminal and hit enter to see and understand description of all the options at your disposal..

Also you can check the [document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm).